# How WCF request is handled in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-8

I am working on a project to improve the performance of WCF service. We have WCF service hosted on IIS server. 
I went through various articles to understand the End to End flow from WCF client to request processing by WCF service.

Kindly clarify the below questions:

1. What happens in IIS when the WCF request comes from the client?
2. How the IIS identifies the request is for particular WCF service (assume that there are multiple WCF services hosted in the IIS)?
3. How IIS is delegating the request processing to WCF service?
4. Who is responsible for creating the WCF service instance?
5. How the ASP.Net worker threads come into WCF service processing request?
6. What is the role of Application pool settings in WCF service request processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requests to the WCF service that is hosted on IIS are handled by WAS (**Windows Activation Service**) which decouples the activation architecture from IIS.
WAS is responsible for processing the requests / response for WCF service.

Here is the high level of what goes on when a http request arrives for a WCF Service hosted on WAS

- Requests are first received by the http.sys kernel.
- A new WAS service is responsible for configuring application pools,
  among other things.
- The WWW Service is responsible for activating application pools and
  requests queues to process incoming requests. In addition, this
  service has a new HTTP Listener Adapter that forwards requests to the
  HttpHandler to process the request (without the need for
  aspnet_isapi.dll).

Keeping above points in mind, here are the best answers that I can come up with.

*Assuming your WCF service is listening on HTTP protocol*

***1.   What happens in IIS when the WCF request comes from the client?***

Everything happens in WAS not IIS.

When a protocol listener ( **HTTP.sys**) picks up a client request, WAS determines if a worker process is running or not. If an application pool already has a worker process that is servicing requests, the listener adapter passes the request onto the worker process for processing. If there is no worker process in the application pool, WAS will start a worker process so that the listener adapter can pass the request to it for processing.

The listener adapter is part of WAS. The request then flows into the worker process’ (w3wp.exe activated by WAS) app domain that has HTTP module and HTTP handler (without the need for aspnet_isapi.dll) that process this request.

***2.   How the IIS identifies the request is for particular WCF service (assume that there are multiple WCF services hosted in the IIS)?***

Its not IIS its WAS that creates a worker process instance (w3wp.exe) and loads application’s code along with other components / network protocols in that worker process. The incomming request has an endpoint address that contains the WCF service name. Also the SOAP message contains the method and the service (class) name which is called by the client. The **Channel Dispatchers** and **Endpoint Dispatchers** use this information to activate the class instance and call the target method.

[Channel and Endpoint Dispatchers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734665(v=vs.110).aspx)

***3.   How IIS is delegating the request processing to WCF service?***

Again its WAS that delegates the request to particular WCF service which it identifies when the request comes in.

***4.   Who is responsible for creating the WCF service instance?***

Dispatchers are responsible for accepting new channels, receiving messages, operation dispatch and **invocation**, and response processing. The answer for question # 2 describes this.

***5.   How the ASP.Net worker threads come into WCF service processing request?***

In IIS 7 and later, Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) manages application pool configuration and worker processes instead of the WWW Service.It manages application pools and worker processes for both HTTP and non-HTTP requests.

HTTP Listener adapter is responsible for bridging requests between WAS and  ASP.Net worker process. For HTTP requests the adapter is provided by www services (w3svc).

***6.   What is the role of Application pool settings in WCF service request processing?***

All of the applications inside an application pool share a common set of run-time characteristics. For example, they all run under the same version of the common language runtime (CLR) and they all share a common process identity. Each application pool corresponds to an instance of a worker process (w3wp.exe). Each managed application running inside of a shared application pool is isolated from other applications by means of a CLR AppDomain.

Once the request arrives at the ServiceHost process, WCF channel dispatchers picks it up and forward to the particular endpoint dispatchers which intern call the method (endpoint) that is responsible to processes the request.

References:

1. Learning WCF: A Hands-on Guide By Michele Leroux Bustamante
2. http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/iis-and-was-hosting-architecture
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677(v=vs.110).aspx
4. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789006(v=vs.110).aspx
5. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734665.aspx
6. https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#WAS

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am marking as "Answer". I am going through the articles and will come back for clarifications if any.